# The second item that I add to a list deletes the first item

Tags: swift

In my Swift 5 code, I have a list named qname and username:

```
var qname = ["myFirstItem", "SecondItem", "Third Item"]
var username = ["Bob", "Joe", "Jill"]
```

I put it in a tableview with

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return qname.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = QuestionTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "question")

    cell?.textLabel?.text = qname[indexPath.row]
    cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(username[indexPath.row])"

    return cell!
}
```

In my other view controller, when the person presses 'post question', I run this code:

```
    @IBAction func postQuestion(_ sender: UIButton) {

    newName = questionName.text!

    newDescription = questionDescription.text!

    newUsername = username.text!

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "madequestion", sender: self)

}
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "madequestion" {
        let vc = segue.destination as! MainPage
        vc.qname.append(newName)
        vc.username.append(newUsername)


    }
}
```

I also have questionName, questionDescription, and username as IBOutlet, just I didn't put it in this code. MainPage is where my tableview is. And the variables I put them in: newName, newDescription, and newUsername were also pre-defined as "".

Now here is the problem. With this code, the `vc.qname.append(newName)` `vc.username.append(newUsername)`is running well the first time I run it, so it adds a question to my tableview. The second time I click post question with different details as newName and newUsername, it overrides the first new question I made and puts the second question.

I would love a pretty simple code explanation since I don't know a lot about coding, if that is possible!

Thank you in advance!

Swaraag

Comment: What's the relationship between `MainPage` and the VC where you post questions? I can see that you can go to the main page from the other VC, but how do you go back to post another question?

Comment: I go to the other VC with a 'ask question' button on the mainPage through the Storyboard . When clicked, it sends to the other VC. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is simple, every time you click "postQuestion" you create a new ViewController which contains your "qname" and "username" array, meaning you insatiate them with your predefine values so every other value you appended gets deleted.

in your case i would probably move your arrays to the ViewController which contains "postQuestion" and every time you click "postQuestion" update the arrays of the "postQuestion" ViewController and then send them to your ViewController which contains the TableView.

it will look something like that:

```
var qname = ["myFirstItem", "SecondItem", "Third Item"]
var username = ["Bob", "Joe", "Jill"]

@IBAction func postQuestion(_ sender: UIButton) {

    newName = questionName.text!

    newDescription = questionDescription.text!

    newUsername = username.text!

    self.qname.append(newName)
    self.username.append(newUsername)
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "madequestion", sender: self)

}
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "madequestion" {
        let vc = segue.destination as! MainPage
        vc.qname = self.qname
        vc.username = self.username
        vc.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

and in your tableViewController the initial values will be as follows:

```
var qname = [String]()
var username = [String]()
```

Comment: I just wanted to make sure, having the same variable but in two different view controllers won't ruin anything? You also wrote ```self.qnam...```. What is the point of the 'self.'? And (the more important question) at the beginning, you defined qname and username. So the first time it will add the item. But the second time, won't it be re-defined to original items, which would delete the appended item/s? And wouldn't that re-write the MainPage VC qname, which will then be put into the tableView? And what does 
vc.tableView.reloadData() do? Thank you though for taking the time to answer this!

Comment: thats a lot of questions..., first self is reference to the object you currently resides in, it will be redefined but the added values wont be deleted, reloadData() is a UITableView func for refreshing your tableView data it will call all the implemented functions again such as: numberOfRowsInSection, cellForRow and more.... you generally use it if you updated  the data of the tableView

Comment: I am getting an error on the 'vc.tableView.reloadData()' saying: Ambiguous reference to member 'tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)'. What did I do wrong?

Comment: try removing the 'vc.tableView.reloadData()'

Comment: Another problem is that the first initial three 'FirstItem', 'SecondItem', 'ThirdItem' won't show on the screen until after you click post question the first time. Also, it still deletes the first item added to the tableView.

Comment: Can you post all the first and ViewController Code after the changes?

Comment: Do you want me to post the code from MainPage VC or the AskQuestion VC? (also, I don't know if it is smaller than 600 characters...)

Comment: Aviv Frenkel, what should I send?